# SQL Get Data from everyday from a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to build a chart where it shows data per day based on multiple filters ( week, month, custom date range ).

The problem is that on my database i only have the date from when the records are created, which means

```
where Date >= @start AND Date <= @start
```

will not return rows for days without records.

I would like it to return a row with result of 0 for those days but I have no idea how to do this in SQL

Data example

```
2019-09-13 12:00:43.7761868
2019-09-13 12:01:20.8275512
2019-09-13 21:28:59.3311800
2019-09-13 21:32:12.8601389
2019-09-14 04:37:25.6108193
2019-09-16 13:34:39.7449688
2019-09-16 14:06:18.0098897
2019-09-16 14:59:22.4131463
2019-09-16 15:00:38.8086073
2019-09-17 05:45:06.9280049
2019-09-17 05:45:50.1708972
2019-09-17 13:50:23.9503997
2019-09-17 13:55:13.1940063
2019-09-17 18:40:26.3523765
2019-09-17 18:41:08.2932910
2019-09-18 03:48:59.2092904
2019-09-18 03:49:41.0802705
2019-09-18 06:10:47.0732559
2019-09-18 06:11:30.1833908
```

note there is no records on the date

```
2019-09-15
```

the intended result would be

```
2019-09-13 
2019-09-14 
2019-09-15
2019-09-16 
2019-09-17 
2019-09-18
```

Comment: It seems like you want `NOT IN()` but _"to return a row with result of 0 for those days"_ is unclear. When you say a row that means result is 1, in other hand you say result of 0.
Please, edit your question to include sample data and desired results as _formatted text_ not images.

Comment: You need a calendar table - either a static one (preferable) or a dynamically-built one. You outer join from the calendar to your data and aggregate on the desired basis (daily, monthly, etc). With the outer join, your results contain at least one row for every date. There are many discussion about this sort of thing.

Comment: updated post with data example

Comment: @SMor I see, i will try this approach

Comment: Agree with @SMor. Here is link you might find helpful: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Pseudo code for creating a Calendar table using a Common Table Expression (CTE) 
--and Custom date range

DECLARE @StartDate datetime,@EndDate datetime

SET @StartDate = '2019-09-13'
SET @EndDate = '2019-09-18'

;WITH CalendarDates(DATEPARAM) AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS datetime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEPARAM)
    FROM CalendarDates
    WHERE DATEPARAM < @EndDate 
) 
SELECT CD.DATEPARAM ,count(convert(date,T.testdate)) as records_on_theday
FROM @T T
Right outer join CalendarDates CD on CD.DATEPARAM = convert(date,T.testdate)
Group By convert(date,T.testdate),CD.DATEPARAM
```

[Sample Code Here..](https://rextester.com/VXVDHC73936)

In the code example above let's assume the search is based on a given start and end date (custom date range filter). So the `CalendarDates` CTE will give all the dates between this range. The `Right Outer Join` with the source table will give the count of records you want as final output. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

**For Year**

```
 SELECT * FROM  YourTableName WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Date_ColumnName) = @Year
```

**For Month**

```
SELECT * FROM  YourTableName WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, Date_ColumnName) = @Month
```

**For Day**

```
  SELECT * FROM  YourTableName WHERE DATEPART(DAY, Date_ColumnName) = @Day
```

**Custom Date Range**

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName
WHERE 
convert(DATETIME,Date_ColumnName)  
BETWEEN Convert(DATETIME,CASE WHEN isnull(@FromDate,'')='' THEN Date_ColumnName
ELSE isnull(@FromDate,'') END)                     
AND Convert(DATETIME, CASE WHEN isnull(@ToDate,'')='' THEN Date_ColumnName 
ELSE isnull(@ToDate,'') END)
```

Note:- You can try this all Query...null part is also Handle in Custom Date Range.....i have already tested it out...

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. I edited my post with a data example. Hope it helps